# How I can get products with random order?

Tags: magento2.4

I am making a custom module and I want to get 5 random product skus. So far I tried:

```
$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();

/**
 * @var ProductRepository
 */
$productRepository = $objectManager->create(ProductRepository::class);

/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
$searchCriteria = $objectManager->create(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
$searchCriteria->addSortOrder(new SortOrder());
$skus = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

But how I can define that I want the skus to be retrieved in random order?

Answer (score 0):

Well using `ProductRepository` is not an option in your case. How about using the `ProductCollectionFactory` instead?

```php
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;


// Rest of code reside here (eg. class definition)

 $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();

/**
 * @var ProductCollectionFactory
 */
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create(ProductCollectionFactory::class);

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->setPageSize(5);
$productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand('sku');

$skus = $productCollection->load()->getData();
$skus = array_map(function($item){return $item['sku'];},$skus);
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a list of product SKUs in random order using Magento 2's ProductRepository and SearchCriteriaBuilder, you can modify your code to include a random sort order. Here's how you can achieve this:

```php
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;

class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ConfigLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $configLoader;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->configLoader = $configLoader;
    }

    public function getRandomProductSkus()
    {
        // Create a random sort order
        $sortOrder = new SortOrder();
        $sortOrder->setField('rand'); // 'rand' is not a native Magento field; you'll need to create a custom attribute for random sorting.

        // Set the random sort order in the search criteria
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($sortOrder);

        // Build the search criteria
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

        // Get the list of products
        $productList = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        // Extract SKUs from the products
        $skus = [];
        foreach ($productList->getItems() as $product) {
            $skus[] = $product->getSku();
        }

        return $skus;
    }
}
```

Comment: `'rand' is not a native Magento field; you'll need to create a custom attribute for random sorting` <<< How I can do that?

Comment: Create a 'rand' attribute by default magento 2 admin, i.e., catalog -> attributes, or create a custom attribute using code for getting random SKU's.